# Ruby ending if block

Tags: ruby

I am a total beginner to Ruby. I am trying to print if an object is an array or an integer, but I am getting a syntax error I cannot figure how to solve it.

```
D:\Ruby>ruby -c Learning-Ruby\loops_stuff.rb
Learning-Ruby/loops_stuff.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end
Learning-Ruby/loops_stuff.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

This is my code

```
obj = ["a", 1, 3.6]

if object.is_a(obj)
    puts "Is array: "
    obj.each do |index|
        puts index
elseif object.is_i(obj)
    puts "Is integer: {#obj}"
else
    puts "Is neither array or integer"
end
```

Comment: `index` is somewhat misleading because `each` yields the array's elements, not indices. A better variable name would be `item` or `element`.

Comment: You have to close the `.each` too. Every `do` and `begin` must have its matching `end`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the rep drop, this site is so friendly with people learning programming. -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the keyword is elsif (without the e in the middle)

```
obj = ["a", 1, 3.6]

if obj.is_a?(Array)
  puts "Is array: "
  obj.each do |index|
    puts index
  end
elsif obj.is_a?(Integer)
  puts "Is integer: #{obj}"
else
  puts "Is neither array or integer"
end
```

also stumbled over this in my first ruby sessions

Comment: you are right @Stefan, edited my post

Answer (score 2):

For addition, you can use `case..when` statement (looks more elegant as for me):

```
case obj
when Integer
  #some actions
when Array 
  #some actions
else
  #some actions
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the strings you print, this might be what you want to code.

```
obj = ["a", 1, 3.6]

if obj.is_a?(Array)
    puts "Is array: "
    obj.each do |index|
        puts index
    end
elsif obj.is_a?(Integer)
    puts "Is integer: {#obj}"
else
    puts "Is neither array or integer"
end
```

The output is:

```
Is array: 
a
1
3.6
```